# Multiple COUNT(DISTINCT) AS with GROUP BY in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to run this query or something that will produce similar output from Rails:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value1') AS Value1, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value2') AS Value2, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value3') AS Value3, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value4') AS Value4, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value5') AS Value5, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value6') AS Value6, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value7') AS Value7, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value8') AS Value8, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value9') AS Value9, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value10') AS Value10, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value11') AS Value11, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value12') AS Value12, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value13') AS Value13, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value14') AS Value14, 
COUNT(DISTINCT columnName = 'Value15') AS Value15, 
unix_timestamp(timestamp) div 300 AS unix_timestamp_timestamp_div_300 
FROM `table` WHERE (timestamp > '2013-12-15 15:50:00 -0800')
GROUP BY unix_timestamp(timestamp) div 300
```

I have tried multiple versions of .count with options and without, and .group, all without luck.

Edit:
For clarification, the goal is to get a row for every 5 minutes with a count of how many rows of each Value# label there were in that 5 minutes.  This will then be used to create a graph with a data series for each Value#.

Edit 2 as Gordon Linhoff pointed out below, the query should be:

```
SELECT 
    sum(columnName = 'Value1') AS Value1, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value2') AS Value2, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value3') AS Value3, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value4') AS Value4, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value5') AS Value5, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value6') AS Value6, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value7') AS Value7, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value8') AS Value8, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value9') AS Value9, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value10') AS Value10, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value11') AS Value11, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value12') AS Value12, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value13') AS Value13, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value14') AS Value14, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value15') AS Value15, 
    unix_timestamp(timestamp) div 300 AS unix_timestamp_timestamp_div_300 
FROM `table`
WHERE (timestamp > '2013-12-15 15:50:00 -0800')
GROUP BY unix_timestamp(timestamp) div 300
```

So the mySQL is now fixed, any help on getting Rails to return something besides a bunch of model => nil objects?

Comment: Why not adding columnName to GROUP ? Are Value1,2,3 etc really needed in separate columns ? and .... (DISTINCT columnName = 'string') is the same as DISTINCT(IF(columnName='string',1,0)), it may not be what you need..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution after internalizing Gordon's answer.

```
pollEvery = 300 # Five Minutes
graphLength = 2592000 # About a month
now = (Time.now.utc.to_i / pollEvery) * pollEvery
start_time = now - graphLength

distinctValues = ModelName.where("created_at > ?", start_time).uniq.pluck(:columnName)

sumClauses = Array.new
distinctValues.each do |value|
  clause = "SUM( hangup_cause = '#{value}') AS #{value}"
  sumClauses.push(clause)
end

selectClause = sumClauses.join(', ') + ", created_at"

data = ModelName.group("unix_timestamp(created_at) div #{pollEvery}").select(selectClause).where('created_at > ?', Time.at(start_time))

data.each do |row|
  # You can loop through the distinctValues to get the data 
  # using row[value] in a distinctValues.each do |value| loop
  # The created_at timestamp for each grouping is available as well
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `count(distinct)` is going to return 0 or 1 depending on whether rows match the condition or not.  That is, the condition only returns two values, 0 or 1.  Change the `count(distinct)` to `sum()`:

```
SELECT 
    sum(columnName = 'Value1') AS Value1, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value2') AS Value2, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value3') AS Value3, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value4') AS Value4, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value5') AS Value5, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value6') AS Value6, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value7') AS Value7, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value8') AS Value8, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value9') AS Value9, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value10') AS Value10, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value11') AS Value11, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value12') AS Value12, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value13') AS Value13, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value14') AS Value14, 
    sum(columnName = 'Value15') AS Value15, 
    unix_timestamp(timestamp) div 300 AS unix_timestamp_timestamp_div_300 
FROM `table`
WHERE (timestamp > '2013-12-15 15:50:00 -0800')
GROUP BY unix_timestamp(timestamp) div 300
```

Comment: Ah, man...  You are correct.  That should definitely be what it is.  I still need to get Rails to get the result of what your query returns, but that is a step closer to what I need.  Thanks.